# snowflake LISTAGG as `in`

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, listagg, snowflake-task

I am trying to use snowflake LISTAGG function in my sub query
This is how I am doing, but I get no results:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE uuid IN (SELECT LISTAGG(''''||uuid||'''', ',') as UUIDS from same_table WHERE condition1 = true AND condition2 = true ORDER BY some_variable)
```

when I just run the subquery it gives me correct results like this

```
SELECT LISTAGG(''''||UUID||'''', ',') AS UUIDS FROM same_table WHERE condition1 = true AND condition2 = true ORDER BY some_variable

Result:
'ad','adsa','sad'
```

it gives me correct result when I use the query directly like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE uuid IN ('ad','adsa','sad')
```

but I am not able to figure out why it doesn't work in the IN clause directly.
Any help will be appreciated

uuid is a varchar(13) if that helps

EDIT:
Hi @FelipeHoffa. I have to use aggregation as eventually I have to get UUIDs in one column that I use it in another query. Imagine if you have multiple columns like this:

```
uuid.                amount              tax
adsa.                  5000.             100
ad.                     100.              10
sad.                   7000.             154
```

then I want something like

```
uuids.                              amount.            tax.  
'ad, adsa, sad'.                     12100.            264.
```

Comment: Why the need for `LISTAGG()`? You could probably do an `IN()` without it.

Answer (score 0):

why would it work? Listagg creates you a single string, while IN is looking in a set of values (like a column).

So if you do a listagg you'll get 'a, b, c' instead of ['a', 'b', 'c'] and in the end your IN will work for 'a, b, c' string but not for 'a' nor 'b' nor 'c'. To find any of those you'll need to use a substring. Here's some examples:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-listagg/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example input and output in your edit, something like this should work:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(uuid), SUM(amount), SUM(tax)
FROM TABLE
WHERE uuid IN
    (SELECT uuid
     FROM same_table
     WHERE condition1 = TRUE
       AND condition2 = TRUE
     )
;
```

If that's not what you're looking for, it would help to have a more complete example of the input and desired output.

You might also want to add a distinct, ie listagg(distinct uuid), if you don't want repeats of the same uuid.